# Install Ubuntu HP Mini

Tags: hp

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my HP mini.

I downloaded the 32 bit version, and I have added it to a USB stick.

Runs on my desktop PC, but it only comes to a black screen with a blinking cursor on it (on the mini). The loading screen doesn't show or anything.

I have tried re-formatting and replacing the files on the stick. Same problem. Nothing loads.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIF8e_5F9B4

Watch this and download that usb program. Just make sure to select lubuntu and the rest is pretty intuitive. You'll have a working usb stick to install lubuntu on the hp mini.